# Token revocation policy can not work

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have read the document as below https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims.md

and we found the token revocation policy is so clear : if a user changes their password, then they may have to re-authenticate. BUT we tested again and again, looks like this policy is not work for us: The original access_token and refresh_token can still use without any error. Is it make sense? Or anything we missed?

[token revocation policy in document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWO95.png)

We tested in this way. Let's see if there are any problems.

1. The first time user login to the application, they enter their
   credential, and the application obtain the access_token to access
   the resource.
2. The application save the access_token, and Use this information
   directly in the next request.
3. When the access_token expired, the
   application use the refresh_token to obtain an new access_token
4. Users may modify their passwords for a variety of reasons, We expect
   the original token to be revoked automatically and prompt use to
   re-authenticate next time
5. We cannot see the behavior as expectation